# Select Option (for dropdown) Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, dropdown

I make a dropdown for a form, I will show the code below. However, when I click the submit button, there is an error saying,
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'brand' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `supplier_details`.
The data that I chose from the dropdown is actually null. Actually, I'm new to Laravel.
I don't want to make a dropdown list from a database, I just want to display the option and the option will be inserted into the database when the user clicks the submit button after filling in the form.

```
    <div class="form-group row">
            <label style="font-size: 16px;" for="id" class = "col-sm-2">Item Brand </label>
            <label for="supp_name" class = "col-sm-1">:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <select name="brand" class="form-control js-example-basic-single" required>
                    <option >Please select item brand</option>  
                    <option value="machine1"> Item Brand 1 </option>  
                    <option value="machine1"> Item Brand 2 </option>  
                    <option value="machine1"> Tem Brand 3 </option>  
                    </select>
                </div>  
         </div>
```

Controller

```
public function createsupplierdetails()
        {
            return view ('frontend.praiBarcode.getweight');
        }

    public function supplierdetails(Request $r)
    {

       $details = new SupplierDetail;
       $getuserPO = Supplier::where('PO',$r->PO)->first();

        $details->brand = $getuserPO->brand;
        $details->container_no = $getuserPO->container_no;
        $details->date_received = $getuserPO->date_received;
        $details->gross_weight = $getuserPO->gross_weight;
        $details->tare_weight = $getuserPO->tare_weight;
        $details->net_weight = $getuserPO->net_weight;
        $details->save();

        return view ('frontend.praiBarcode.viewsupplierdetails')
        ->with('details',$details);
        
        }
```

Comment: Show your controller code.

Comment: From which element do you get the value `$r->PO`?

Comment: pls dd($r->all()); and add your dump data here

Answer (score 0):

This to check to verify if it is working:

1. Make sure you are submitting the correct form.
2. Try doing `dd` on your controller `dd($request->all())`
3. If data is reaching the controller and not inserted into the database, check on your model, if it is added to `fillable` or if there is only `id` in the guarded array. You can know about more here in https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Error should be fixed, as soon as you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**
use Validator;

```
  public function store(Request $request)

  {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

        'brand' => 'required',
        
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', $validator->errors()->first());
    }
    $details = new SupplierDetail();

    $details->brand = $request->brand;
    $details->container_no = $request->container_no;
    $details->date_received = $request->date_received;
    $details->gross_weight = $request->gross_weight;
    $details->tare_weight = $request->tare_weight;
    $details->net_weight = $request->net_weight;
    $details->save();
    if ($trending) {
        return redirect(route('details.index'))->with('success', 'Field added successfully');
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Field has been not added successfully');
    }
}
```